# Azure IoT Edge metrics-collector authentication to Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm using the very interesting IoT Edge module Metrics-Collector and its working fine with the Log Analytics Workspace. My question is probably more towards the authentication of the metrics-collector module against the log analytics workspace.

For option 1 in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-edge/how-to-collect-and-transport-metrics?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=iothub#upload-target) we need to use the Workspace ID and key [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agent-windows?view=iotedge-2020-11#workspace-id-and-key). The possible security issue I see is that the same key would be used in all Edge devices and if the key is compromised some malicious logs could be entered into the monitoring.

Now my question is if there is an option to create some sort of SAS to connect to the Log Analytics Workspace for "inserting" the data. Or is the solution to use option 2 or to rotate the log analytics workspace key and distribute this to the edge devices?

Thanks & regards,
Gerhard

Comment: Key rotation could work, but have you considered configuring the module to send telemetry [over D2C messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-edge/how-to-collect-and-transport-metrics?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=iothub#upload-target) instead? You could then push the messages into Log Analytics on the cloud side.

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer thanks for your comment. Yes that is my fallback option. However I was wondering if there is an option to still use the direct insert into Log Analytics Workspace.